# Adding checkbox dynamically

Tags: c#

Can anyone please help me out...I'm trying to create checkboxes dynamically in a form which get their data from a list items...

Comment: Winforms or ASP.NET?  Need a lot more detail here.

Answer (score 2):

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
this.Controls.Add(chk);
```

See **[Adding Controls at Run Time (Visual C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287574(VS.71).aspx)**